# How to share data between pages after form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the REGISTER page!</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
            <script> 
        function submitRegForm () {
            var user=document.forms[username][usr].value;
            var pass=document.forms[username][pwd].value;
            var bday=document.forms[username][dob].value;
            var loggedin=document.forms[username][loggedin]=false;
            confirm("succesfully registered");
        }

        </script>


         <div align="left">
             <form name="Register" action="submitRegForm()" >
                        Username *: <input  type="username" name="username" />
                         <br>
                         <br>
            Password *: <input type="password" name="pwd" />
                         <br>
                         <br>
                        Date of Birth *: <input type="date of birth" name="dob" />
                         <br>
                         <br>


        <input  type="submit" value="Submit" />

            </form>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="window.location='index.html'">Return to main page!</button>


    </body>
</html>
```

for the TL;DR of you , (literally only a couple hours into using JS ) im in a need of sharing the document forms or whatnot with other pages , i have two more pages , one being the main screen , second is login and the last one is the register .

Do i direct the forms to a specific folder? is there another way to actually do this? i was reading a bit about PHP, read that it basically saves all of those forms if i ask it to for the current session between all pages?if that is infact the case i still have the issue of how to store all of those registered users? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're doing at the moment is all wrong. The action of the form should be the target of where it's being submitted to. If the method is GET, then the form's value will be appended to the query string of the action. You can then pull the values from the querystring in your receiving page. If it's a POST, then the values will be posted to the page/controller, etc, instead. And you can then process those posted values from there from the request. You don't need that JavaScript function, unless you wish to do some client side validation, or some other fancy processing prior to submission.

Comment: And you would use the onsubmit handler of a form for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not capable of providing a tutorial for beginners. We can help with `specific` problems. So, if you get stuck at a certain point, we will help. But probably you will be fine with google, for the first weeks. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic